# xUnit Visual Studio Test in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, xunit, azure-pipelines

I try to setup asp.net core 1.0 test using xunit test in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online), no matter i try it not able to find the assemblies.

Project

> \src
>   \test --Folder
>   \test\Job.Core.Tests -- project name

Visual Studio Test Setting:

> Test Assembly: **\$(BuildConfiguration)*tests*.dll;-:**\obj**
>   Code Coverage Enabled: true
>   VSTest version: Visual Studio 2015
>   Path to Custom Test Adapters: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages
>   Other console options: /InIsolation
>   Platform: $(BuildPlatform)
>   Configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)

may I know where i goes wrong.

> 2016-04-09T05:27:33.1647258Z Executing the powershell script: `C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.97.1\tasks\VSTest\1.0.34\VSTest.ps1`
>
> 2016-04-09T05:27:35.3816395Z ##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: '**\release*test*.dll;-:**\obj**'.

Answer (score 0):

The default templates available on vso-build provides an example of what you want. If you create a new build definition and then select Visual Studio as the default template, you get a Visual Studio Test task which tries to discover all dlls which has 'test' in their name.

The test assembly name should be in this format.

`**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**`

Also make sure that you set the working folder to the proper location so that it can find the dlls using the search pattern mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a same approach to implement xUnit test in Asp.Net Core project as this link: [Getting Started with xUnit.net (DNX / ASP.NET 5)](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html).

Generally, the build output directory for Asp.Net Core project is a bit different with other projects. The compiled dlls are placed in $(BuildConfiguration)\dnx451 folder. This depends on the framework you use. To find these files, update the path of Test Assemblies to following:

```
**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**
```

Comment: Yes am using the same approach, out of luck trying for several days not able to fix this.

Comment: No test assemblies found matching the pattern: '**\release\*\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**'.

Comment: @tomato45un I added one more "\*" in the Test Assemblies path, did you try with that? And can you share a screenshot for that settings?